# Order of Events at the End of Days

Tags: messiah

Is there a specific order of events that will take place at the End of Days  such as building the Bais Hamikdash and the War of Gog Umagog?

Comment: There are such listings found within Torah but many people rely upon Rambam's comment from the end of Mishnah Torah that the precise meaning of these things will not be known for certain until they actually occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rambam in Hilchos Melachim 12:2 says

> מפשוטן של דברי הנביאים שבתחילת ימות המשיח תהיה מלחמת גוג ומגוג ושקודם מלחמת גוג ומגוג יעמוד נביא לישר ישראל ולהכין לבם  שנאמר הנה אנכי שולח לכם את אליה
>
> The simple interpretation of the prophets' words appear to imply that the war of Gog and Magog will take place at the beginning of the Messianic age. Before the war of Gog and Magog, a prophet will arise to inspire Israel to be upright and prepare their hearts, as Malachi 3:22 states: 'Behold, I am sending you Elijah.'

As outlined in 12:3 The determination of lineage.

> בימי המלך המשיח כשתתיישב ממלכתו ויתקבצו אליו כל ישראל יתייחסו כולם על פיו ברוח הקודש שתנוח עליו שנאמר וישב מצרף ומטהר וגו' ובני לוי מטהר תחילה ואומר זה מיוחס כהן וזה מיוחס לוי ודוחה את שאינן מיוחסין לישראל הרי הוא אומר ויאמר התרשתא להם וגו' עד עמוד כהן לאורים ולתומים הנה למדת שברוח הקודש מייחסין המוחזקין ומודיעין המיוחס ואינו מייחס ישראל אלא לשבטיהם שמודיע שזה משבט פלוני וזה משבט פלוני אבל אינו אומר על שהן בחזקת כשרות זה ממזר וזה עבד שהדין הוא שמשפחה שנטמעה נטמעה
>
> During the era of the Messianic king, once his kingdom has been established and all of Israel has gathered around him, the entire nation's line of descent will be established on the basis of his words and the prophetic spirit which will rest upon him, as Malachi 3:3 states: 'He shall sit as a refiner and purifier.'
>
> He will purify the lineage of the Levites first, stating 'He is a priest of defined lineage. He is a Levite of defined lineage.' Those whose lineage he will not recognize will be lowered to the status of Israelites. This is implied by Ezra 2:63: 'The governor said to them: 'They should not eat of the most holy things until a priest arises who will wear the urim vitumim.' From this verse, you can infer that the prophetic spirit will be used to define and notify the pedigree of lineage.
>
> When he defines the lineage of the Israelites, he will make known their tribal lineage alone, stating: 'He is from this tribe and he is from another tribe.' He will not, by contrast, state concerning a person who is presumed to be of unblemished lineage: 'He is illegitimate or he is of slave lineage.' For the law is once a family has become intermingled with the entire Jewish people, they may remain intermingled.

Back to 11:1 Ingathering and rebuilding the Bayis Shlishi (third temple) restoring the Monarchy and sacrifices.

> המלך המשיח עתיד לעמוד ולהחזיר מלכות דוד ליושנה לממשלה הראשונה ובונה המקדש ומקבץ נדחי ישראל וחוזרין כל המשפטים בימיו כשהיו מקודם מקריבין קרבנות ועושין שמטין ויובלות ככל מצותה האמורה בתורה
>
> In the future, the Messianic king will arise and renew the Davidic dynasty, restoring it to its initial sovereignty. He will build the Temple and gather the dispersed of Israel.
>
> Then, in his days, the observance of all the statutes will return to their previous state. We will offer sacrifices, observe the Sabbatical and Jubilee years according to all their particulars as described by the Torah.

11:4 The general orders seems to be most clear from here. Bring all the Jews back to observance, war, build Bayis Shlishi (third temple) and bring all Jews to Eretz Hakedosha (the Holy land). Lastly convince the nations of the world (non jews) to become Monotheistic and see the light of the Torah.

> ואם יעמוד מלך מבית דויד הוגה בתורה ועוסק במצות כדויד אביו כפי תורה שבכתב ושבעל פה ויכוף כל ישראל לילך בה ולחזק בדקה וילחם מלחמות ה' הרי זה בחזקת שהוא משיח אם עשה והצליח ובנה מקדש במקומו וקבץ נדחי ישראל הרי זה משיח בודאי ויתקן את העולם כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד שנאמר כי אז אהפוך אל עמים שפה ברורה לקרוא כולם בשם ה' ולעבדו שכם אחד.
>
> If a king will arise from the House of David who diligently contemplates the Torah and observes its mitzvot as prescribed by the Written Law and the Oral Law as David, his ancestor, will compel all of Israel to walk in (the way of the Torah) and rectify the breaches in its observance, and fight the wars of God, we may, with assurance, consider him Mashiach.
>
> If he succeeds in the above, builds the Temple in its place, and gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Mashiach.
>
> He will then improve the entire world, motivating all the nations to serve God together, as Tzephaniah 3:9 states: 'I will transform the peoples to a purer language that they all will call upon the name of God and serve Him with one purpose.'

**Disclaimer from the Rambam**

> וכל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן לא ידע אדם איך יהיו עד שיהיו שדברים סתומין הן אצל הנביאים גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו אלא לפי הכרע הפסוקים ולפיכך יש להם מחלוקת בדברים אלו ועל כל פנים אין סדור הויית דברים אלו ולא דקדוקיהן עיקר בדת
>
> All these and similar matters cannot be definitely known by man until they occur for these matters are undefined in the prophets' words and even the wise men have no established tradition regarding these matters except their own interpretation of the verses. Therefore, there is a controversy among them regarding these matters.
>
> Regardless of the debate concerning these questions, neither the order of the occurrence of these events or their precise detail are among the fundamental principles of the faith.

Answer (score 0):

Rebbe Shimon bar Yochai ([*Toldos*](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.140a.51?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) 140a) says the following:

אָמַר רַב יוֹסֵף, וְכִי יְמוֹת הַמָּשִׁיחַ וּתְחִיַּת הַמֵּתִים אֵינָם אֶחָד? אָמַר לוֹ, לֹא, שֶׁשָּׁנִינוּ, בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ קוֹדֵם לְקִבּוּץ גָּלֻיּוֹת, קִבּוּץ גָּלֻיּוֹת קוֹדֵם לִתְחִיַּת הַמֵּתִים, וּתְחִיַּת הַמֵּתִים הָאַחֲרוֹן שֶׁבְּכֻלָּם, *Rav Yosef asked, "Are the Messianic times and the Resurrection of the Dead one and the same?" Rav Nachman told him, "No. For we learn that the [rebuilding of the] Beis HaMikdash precedes the Ingathering of Exiles. The Ingathering of Exiles precedes the Resurrection of the Dead. Resurrection of the Dead is the last of all of them"*

מִנַּיִן לָנוּ? שֶׁכָּתוּב (תהלים קמו) בּוֹנֵה יְרוּשָׁלַיִם ה' נִדְחֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל יְכַנֵּס. הָרוֹפֵא לִשְׁבוּרֵי לֵב וּמְחַבֵּשׁ לְעַצְבוֹתָם. זוֹ הִיא תְחִיַּת הַמֵּתִים שֶׁהִיא הָרְפוּאָה לִשְׁבוּרֵי לֵב עַל מֵתֵיהֶם. בּוֹנֵה יְרוּשָׁלַיִם תְּחִלָּה, וְאַחֲרָיו נִדְחֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל יְכַנֵּס, וְהָרוֹפֵא לִשְׁבוּרֵי לֵב אַחֲרוֹן עַל הַכֹּל,

[The question is] where do we learn this out from? It’s written, *“The Builder of Yerushalayim is Hashem; the outcast of Israel He will gather in. He is the Healer of the brokenhearted and the One Who binds up their sorrows”* (Tehillim 147:2-3). 'Resurrection of the Dead’ is referenced to ‘He heals the broken hearts’ of the dead. ‘The Builder of Yerushalayim’ is mentioned first, followed by ‘the outcast of Israel He will gather in’ and concludes with ‘He is the Healer of the brokenhearted’

Here’s a summary of the order of how Final Redemption will take place:

1. Rebuilding of the Beis HaMikdosh,
2. Ingathering of the exiles,
3. Resurrection of the Dead.