# Judaism's position on the coming of the Messiah and the ingathering of the exiles

Tags: messiah

Is there a prophesy within Judaism, that Jews will gather in Israel and then Messiah will descend?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of sources that stress that Moshiach will come, and then we will be gathered to Eretz Yisrael from the "four corners of the world". See for example Yirmiyahu 29:14.

The Rambam rules clearly, that it will be Moshiach who will gather us, and that we are not the ones who will do that. Refer to Hilchos Melachum U'Milchamos, chapter 11:

> In the future, the Messianic king will arise and renew the Davidic dynasty, restoring it to its initial sovereignty. He will build the Temple and gather the dispersed of Israel.

Rabbi Yitzchok Weiss, the Spinker Rebbe quotes the Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 56:2), which quotes the posuk in zecharyah 9:9. The Spinker Rebbe comments on this Midrash that we need to "sit" in exile, e.g. We are not meant to hasten the geulah. We are not meant to force the end so to speak. Why not? Because Moshiach is the one who we are waiting for (Chakal Yitzchak, Parashas Vayeira, p. 40). We are not to go up without the donkey, e.g. Melech HaMoshiach, who will come and gather in the Jewish people from exile.

See also the newspaper called HaPardes [(HaPardes No.11, v. 5 1937, p. 9)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12083&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=) where some great rabbi's of that time warned that the ingathering during 1948 would be not in line what the Torah teaches us, and that it goes straight against our belief that Moshiach will take us back.

Refer to Uvdos VeHanhagos Lebeis Brisk (vol. 4, p. 195) where it says that we must hold on to our faith that it is Moshiach who will pick us up and bring us to EY.

> צריך להתחזק ולהאמין שהגלות נגזרה עלינו מאת השי"ת ולחכות בסבלנות שהוא
> יתברך יגאלנו ויושיענו ע"י משיח צדקנו ולעמוד בנסיונות

The Chofetz Chaim, Chofetz Chaim Al HaTorah, Parashas Bo, p. 99, said, according to what his son Rabbi Leib Kagan heard, that when the English Government signed the Balfour Declaration, there was an awakening for the Geulah in Shamayim, but the opportunity was taken away by the people involved in it. Says the Chofetz Chaim "they don't wait for G-d anymore"

> ‎ליותר הם לא מחכים אוי מה הי' לנו והמשיך לבכות

Cited in Uvdos Vehanhagos Leveis Brisk, vol. 4, p. 207 but I have a physical copy of Chofetz Chaim Al HaTorah here in front of me (p. 100, footnote).

So according to the above, it will be Moshiach who will gather us and not otherwise around. We are not meant to force the end and "do the job for G-d". We are meant to, to cite the Midrash and the Spinker Rav, sit in exile until Hashem takes us out of here and returns us to Eretz Yisrael.

The Rambam rules clearly about this, but this could also be found in [a plethora of locations throughout the Tanach](https://www.truetorahjews.org/qanda/sources) and Talmud/Midrash.

Comment: This is outright misleading. The Rambam rules shortly after what you reference that these are all guesses and no one knows for sure the exact sequence of events and none of the guesses are fundamentals of faith https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82257/759

Comment: So we are not meant to "await him" and the Torah does not teach us that Moshiach will be the one who will gather the dispersed from the four corners of the world?

Comment: No one knows. We just follow halacha and God will figure it out. That's the Jewish way.

Comment: So all these sources in the last linked article do not say that Moshiach will be the one? Abarbanel on Devarim 30:3 says so. What about Yechezkel 20:41-42 and so on.. There are prophecies that say so. If they did not tell us, then yes, you are right. But there are.

Comment: They are all guesses. That's literally what the Rambam says and you know it. I don't need to explain this to you.

Comment: So if Yechezkel HaNavi and Yirmiyahu HaNavi tell us that Moshiach will gather us, these are merely guesses?

Comment: I don't need to repeat myself or explain things you already know and are pretending not to.

Comment: Yes you do. If you don't agree with this, please provide sources to back it up. I provided a bunch of sources, including statements from our Prophets. Just saying that it isn't true, is not enough.

Comment: I did provide an explicit source in the Rambam. This is not a matter of agreeing or not. I don't know the order either. I just have my guesses.

Comment: Proves my point that I made on this site, a long time ago. I was basically saying that parallel Universes can exist without contradicting the Torah. It is possible that the sequence of events regarding the coming of Moshiach will be different in each Universe.

Comment: "No one knows. We just follow halacha and God will figure it out. That's the Jewish way."- The Rambam clearly states before the halacha you quoted (in Perek 11, Halacha 1 and 4) that Moshiach will gather the dispersed. "All these and similar matters cannot be definitely known by man" could refer to Gog UMagog and the coming of Eliyahu, since he says it while describing these two events. Please refer back to Chapter 11, where he clearly says in which order it will happen, and all of this is based on Torah (Yechezkel 20 etc...).